# How to test a Kafka Stream app without duplicating the topology? Use of TopologyTestDriver?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I think I misunderstood something with the TopologyTestDriver.

Until now, when I developed a Kafka Stream app, I connect to a real Kafka in test environment, manually create and fed in-topics, and check the content of what is in the out-topic(s).

In order to automatize the tests, I looked at the `TopologyTestDriver`. According to the documentation published by Confluent ( https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/test-streams.html ), it  seems to be what I am looking for:

> [...] Normally, you run the topology using the KafkaStreams class, which
>   connects to your broker [...].
>   For testing, running a broker  [...] adds a lot of complexity and time.
>
> Streams provides the TopologyTestDriver  [...] replacement for the KafkaStreams class. It has no external system dependencies [...] There are
>   hooks for verifying data sent to output topics [...].

My concern is about the location of the topology. In each example I saw (on Confluent, on Kafka website, ...), the topology  is defined within the test file :

```
private TopologyTestDriver testDriver;
....

@Before
public void setup() {
    Topology topology = new Topology();
    topology.addSource("sourceProcessor", "input-topic");
    .......

    // setup test driver
    Properties config = new Properties();
    ....
    testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, config);

    // pre-populate store
    .....
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    testDriver.close();
}

@Test
public void shouldFlushStoreForFirstInput() {
    testDriver.pipeInput(recordFactory.create("input-topic", "a", 1L, 9999L));
    OutputVerifier.compareKeyValue(......);
    Assert.assertNull(........);
}
```

How can I implement tests for my existing Kafka Streams apps? I cannot imagine I  have to duplicate the code of my topology - one version in my main file and one version in my test file. It would be hard to maintain.

My existing apps have the topology defined directly in the `main` method. I could extract the topology design from the main by adding a static method like `protected static org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology buildTopology() {...}`, and I would be able to call this method from the test file.

But isn't there any cleaner solution to execute the main code from the test code?

Comment: definitely you should not duplicate code. in case of using `Spring`, you could just autowire already existing `Topology` beans into your test class. in case you have `main` method, you could move each topology creation into separate method and invoke each such method from test class.

Comment: I think that adding a `buildTopology()` method is a clean way. Nothing wrong with this IMHO.

Comment: Thank you Matthias and Vasiliy. Agreed to write a buildTopology() method. But now I am facing the "Kafka doesn't work on Windows" issue :( But that's another story. Thank you again!